# jQuery - toggle button show/hide table data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like some help please.

```
<h2>Operating systems <span class="button small toggle-btn">Toggle</span></h2>
<table class="data" cellpadding="8" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="first" style="width:120px">
                Operating System </th>
            <th class="">
                Percentage </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td class="">iOS 8.4</td>
            <td class="">
                <div class="ui-percentage" style="width:17%">17 %</div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="tr even">
            <td class="">iOS 8.3</td>
            <td class="">
                <div class="ui-percentage" style="width:6%">6 %</div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="">iOS 8.2</td>
            <td class="">
                <div class="ui-percentage" style="width:11%">11 %</div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="tr even">
            <td class="">iOS 8.1.3</td>
            <td class="">
                <div class="ui-percentage" style="width:11%">11 %</div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="">iOS 8.1</td>
            <td class="">
                <div class="ui-percentage" style="width:6%">6 %</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When the page loads for the first time I want the table to be collapsed. When I click the Toggle button I want to change the table status, so basically to expand it and collapse it again if the button is clicked again.

This is my script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.toggle-btn').closest('table').hide(); // I want to target the table right after the button
        $('.toggle-btn').on('click', function(event) {
            $(this).closest('table').toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

How can I make this work correct ?

Comment: what is happening are you getting error?

Comment: Your false button (span) isn't descendant of table element. At least you should have checked doc regarding `closest()` method... Now how many table do you get? If only once, target it directly, otherwise use relevant transversal methods, e.g: `$(this).closest('h2').next().toggle();`

Comment: @guradio: No I don't get any erros

Comment: you should use `.parent()` to get the parent and then use `.siblings()` since the table is sibling of the parent of the button

Comment: @guradio: You mean: `$('.toggle-btn').siblings('table').hide();` ??

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/4ca9a0xy/

Comment: @Lykos `$('.toggle-btn').parent().siblings('table').hide();` this one

Comment: something like this maybe https://jsfiddle.net/8wrg6mkp/

Comment: I have to ask it again: `Now how many table do you get?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have only **one** `table` then only do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('tbody').closest('h2').next().find("tbody").hide();
        $('.toggle-btn').on('click', function() {
            $('tbody').toggle();
        });
    });
```

For **more then one sibling tables**

You can find closest `h2` and `next()` gives you `table`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.toggle-btn').closest('h2').next().find("tbody").hide();
        $('.toggle-btn').on('click', function() {
            $(this).closest('h2').next().find("tbody").toggle();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Operating systems <span class="button small toggle-btn">Toggle</span></h2>
<table class="data" cellpadding="8" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="first" style="width:120px">
                Operating System </th>
            <th class="">
                Percentage </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td class="">iOS 8.4</td>
            <td class="">
                <div class="ui-percentage" style="width:17%">17 %</div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="tr even">
            <td class="">iOS 8.3</td>
            <td class="">
                <div class="ui-percentage" style="width:6%">6 %</div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="">iOS 8.2</td>
            <td class="">
                <div class="ui-percentage" style="width:11%">11 %</div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="tr even">
            <td class="">iOS 8.1.3</td>
            <td class="">
                <div class="ui-percentage" style="width:11%">11 %</div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="">iOS 8.1</td>
            <td class="">
                <div class="ui-percentage" style="width:6%">6 %</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yep it seems to work, but how can I collapse/expand only the `tbody` part and not all the `table` ??

Comment: @Lykos i have updated answer to find `tbody` , Please check.

Comment: Yes, its working exactlly as I wanted! thank you for the help! :-)

Comment: If you just want to hide the table body $('tbody').hide() is enough and wont mess up the code if you decide to change the h2 tag or put someting between the tag and the table...

Answer (score 3):

why not just use toggle function directly?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table').hide();
    $('.toggle-btn').on('click', function() {
        $('table').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: That would hide every table in the page

Comment: i think so too @A.Wolff direct approach

Comment: @mikeyq6 OP didnt even mention how many tables there are OP was asked in the comments. OP lack of information

Comment: @mikeyq6 It just looks like OP has only one table and have no idea what he was/is doing. EDIT: i see in OP as comment `// I want to target the table right after the button` so i could be wrong but i asked it twice in comment, still didn't get any answer...

Comment: @A.Wolff i think this should be accepted answer :) . Just make it simple then generic. ;)

Comment: @ParthTrivedi i think only the OP can choose which is he thinks is the accepted answer

Comment: @A.Wolff I see your points. I think the answer could be improved though, by explaining how he's going wrong and what he could do better.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle-btn').parent().next('table').hide(); // I want to target the table right after the button
  $('.toggle-btn').on('click', function(event) {
    $(this).parent().siblings('table').toggle();
  });
});
```

Selector should be `$('.toggle-btn').parent().next('table')`

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/4ca9a0xy/)

Comment: I didn't downvoted but using siblings could match all sibling tables, not only the relevant one. If there is only one, then it doesn't really matter

Comment: @A.Wolff yes you right but since the sample is only i didnt consider that scenario i will add more detail like id so that this will point to the correct table

Comment: Anyway, if only one table, then target it directly using relevant selector, no need of using expensive transversal methods

Comment: @A.Wolff i used `.next()` to be sure that the next table will be selected

Answer (score 0):

the function `closest()` goes up the element's parents, so it will never find the table. You would have to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle-btn').parent().parent().find('table').hide(); // I want to target the table right after the button
    $('.toggle-btn').on('click', function(event) {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('table').toggle();
    });
});
```

But this would not work if there are multiple tables. Consider using an id or for the table, so that you can access it directly. Eg:

```
<table id="data-table-1" class="data" cellpadding="8" border="1">
```

That would make the javascript much simpler, ie:

```
$('.toggle-btn').on('click', function(event) {
    $('#data-table-1').toggle();
});
```